# Transform a string to char in caml

Tags: caml

How I can convert the string "\n"  to the character '\n' in caml.
We don't have a function in caml (char_of_string) which allows some things like that.
For strings like "a","b".. "z" it's easy we take the character number one but when we have characters like "\", how can we do this conversion ?

Answer (score 1):

Char extraction is working:

```
let x = "\n" in
print_string "test";
print_char (x.[0]);
print_string "end";;

test
end
```

Or perhaps you were thinking about pattern matching ?

```
fun x = match x with 
| "\n" -> '\n'
| e -> e.[0]
```